What does "losing one's ass" mean?
I found a joke once that involved a man and his donkey taking a walk, but people are demanding to him, and when he tries to satiate their demands, the donkey ends up falling off a cliff, with the punchline being "If you try to please everyone, you might lose your ass."
I know "ass" is slang for both "buttocks" and "donkey" and thus it's a pun, but I don't know what "losing one's ass" means.

Ass is not slang for an Equus asinus! It is but far the oldest of the terms for this creature in modern use. The problem is that it has become taboo i our day, largely replaced by burros and such. This is the same problem seen with "roosters".

It's in Green's Dictionary of Slang.

It's actually Aesop's fable “The Man, the Boy, and the Donkey”, and the moral of the story isn't that if you try to please everyone ...you might lose your ass - it's that ...you will please no-one.

This Urban Dictionary entry may be helpful:
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Lose%20one%27s%20ass"

Do so bad that you lose even what's impossible to lose, your ass.

See also save your ass, kiss your ass goodbye, ass backwards ... all meaning the whole, darned self.

To improve your answer, you need to quote from your reference.

Urban Dictionary: Lose one's ass
In contemporary slang most often used in somewhat lighthearted exclaiming of fear of "losing/coming out on the losing end/dead last or (and I've noticed this more) in league with like, gambling, casino etc as in...

Jesus Christ, you better get him outta there quick — Jeff sucks at blackjack, he's gonna lose his ass!

Or

Been up all night drinking and  losing my ass at euchre to Donna and your freakin sister! Gimme a break I'll do it later ok?!

Both of these quotes are direct from my dad and myself and we both use this phrase I'd say, somewhat regularly? I got it from my dad who is a boomer and I'm a millennial; I've never used this site before so not sure if it matters but in terms of regional dialect, colloquialisms, etc., we have a Midwest accent: dad is from Buffalo and we live in Detroit.
